# How Spark can speed up bulk loading to JanusGraph?

Tags: apache-spark, bulkinsert, janusgraph

I need to load lots of vertices and edges to JanusGraph with Cassandra backend from other storage. I've read about bulk loading and Spark configuring (https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/bulk-loading/ and https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/hadoop/) .

It's clear how to configure JanusGraph for Spark usage but I'm still not sure how to use Spark then and if Spark can help to speed up inserting into graph.

Please give some use cases and code example of using Hadoop MapReduce or Spark to speed up bulk loading data to Janusgraph (Java or Python are preferred). Any help welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked on POC project recently to Bulk Load data into JanusGraph using Apache Spark. We were getting pretty good performance loading data into using Spark. Setup and sample code is provided in the article below.

https://medium.com/@nitinpoddar/bulk-loading-data-into-janusgraph-ace7d146af05

https://medium.com/@nitinpoddar/bulk-loading-data-into-janusgraph-part-2-ca946db26582

Comment: Please provide at least main points of how you did it (what packages were used, configuration options, etc.), because links could disappear.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can write a Kafka consumer application to load data from your Kafka to JanusGraph. The amount of parallelism will be restricted to the number of partitions of the source/input topic from which your application is reading data. The application will be single-threaded but you can scale your application to the number of input topics. Each instance of your application can open up a connection and write to JanusGraph using a transaction. You can batch transactions with some batch size to spread the load.