# Gremlin: Avoid duplicates without losing perfomance

Tags: python, performance, duplicates, gremlin

I am trying to insert millions of vertex and edges in the shortest time possible with gremlin python.
I have 2 things to consider:
avoid duplicates for both vertex and edges
avoid to spend 10 hours to insert all data

The major time requested is for looking for the existing vertex and create the relationship.
If I insert edges without checking if a vertex already exists, the script is faster.

I have tryed also with batching the transactions like:

```
g.addV("person").property("name", "X").as_("p1")
 .addV("person").property("name", "Y").as_("p2")
 .addE("has_address").from("p1").to(g.V().has("address", "name", "street"))
 .addE("has_address").from("p2").to(g.V().has("address", "name", "street2")).iterate()
```

but I have not improved the performance.

With duplicates I will have the same results in the queries?
I think it would be more expensive later for the queries with duplicates no?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66598714/1831717) to your last question provided some hints on how to load data "fast" and now that I know your size is in the millions I hope you would consider those strategies.

If you happen to continue with loading with Gremlin and Python, then consider the following points:

1. I'm not sure where your duplicates arise from but I would look for opportunities to clean that source data and organize it and the load plan to avoid loading them in the first place which will save you cleanup later. I can't say if duplicates will leave you with the same results in your queries because I don't know your data nor do I know your queries. In some graphs and queries I've known duplicates to be irrelevant and expected and in others it could be a disaster.
2. Definitely try to organize your load into the batching pattern in the [blog post](https://stephen.genoprime.com/snippet/2020/03/28/snippet-7.html) I suggested in my other answer. This approach is faster than building giant chained Gremlin traversals filled with hundreds of `addV()` and `addE()`.
3. Related to item 1, you've seen the performance pain of looking up graph elements prior to insert. Consider pre-sorting your data in such a way as to avoid repeated vertex lookups. Perhaps one way is to load all your vertices first so that you know they exist and then group/sort your edge load in such a way that you find vertices once and load all edges among that neighborhood of vertices.
4. Finally, if you can get 1 and 3 figured out, then perhaps you can parallelize the load.

Again, it's impossible to really offer specifics in this sort of forum, but perhaps these ideas will inspire you to an answer.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your answer. I have a problem of duplicates because I don't import data only one time but I want to keep it updated every day with new information; the new vertex or edges I add to the graph can probably already exists.
I read your blog post but I don't understand how that approch can be faster, I think it has the same timing of execution of the example I wrote in the question. 
I think the problem is to find the vertex or edges already exist because this search slows the importing of data.